# is there any better way then this for chracter replacement in string?

Tags: php, string

I am working on my url to make it pretty. and here is the logic i came up with.

now in the url i want to achieve something like this.

http://domain.com/category/date/post-title

for that i first populated the value from the database, i.e date and the post title like this

for date:

```
$date = date("d", $row['timestamp']);
$month = date("m", $row['timestamp']);
$year = date("Y", $row['timestamp']);
$date_url = $date.$month.$year;
```

for title:

```
$title = $row['title'];
$title_url = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
```

now i created a hyperlink to send it to URL like this.

```
<a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&cat=<?php echo 'news'; ?>&date=<?php echo $date_url; ?>&title=<?php echo $title_url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo 'admin-login/'.$pic_title; ?>"/></a>
```

my main concern is the title, which i am populating the value from the database, is it ok to use `str_replace()` for this? or is there any better way?

do i go wrong anywhere or it is fine to go ahead with this logic?

thank you..

Comment: On an aside, I would recommend compiling your URLs within it's own PHP block and just outputing the URL variable instead of compiling like it is. Readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not considering punctuations and other special char.

You can do:

```
$from = array('/\W/','/-+/','/^-/','/-$/');
$to = array('-','-','','');
$title = preg_replace($from,$to,$title);
```

This will replace any non word char to `-`, replace multiple consecutive `-`'s with one `-` and also delete leading and trailing `-` if any.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$date = date("dmy", $row['timestamp'])
```

For title use preg_replace to remove all illegal characters

```
$title = strtolower(preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '/[ -]+/', '/^-|-$/'), array('', '-', ''), $title));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = preg_replace('/\W/', '-', $row['title']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [sanitize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) all special characters in your title, be sure about all of them are eliminated.